# arkade: set up service as a LoadBalancer

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

how can I achieve that [arkade](https://github.com/alexellis/arkade) will create a service of `type: LoadBalancer` instead of `type: ClusterIP`?

I stumbled upon that requirement while deploying my private `docker-registry`. Logging in, pushing and pulling images from the command line, all runs fine, but once I want to use that registry, I need a point of reference which I state as the image in my Deployment definition:

```
...
      containers:
      - name: pairstorer
        image: 192.168.x.x:5000/myimage:1.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 55555
...
```

If I install the registry using `arkade install docker-registry`, I don't see any options for obtaining an external IP other than `kubectl edit service docker-registry` and adding it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is just a change of `Service` type from `ClusterIP` to `LoadBalancer`, you need to override default value for `docker-registry` Helm Chart.

**Arkade** uses the `stable/docker-registry` Helm chart to install `docker-registry` and you can find default values [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/docker-registry/values.yaml).

You need to change `service.type=ClusterIP` to `service.type=LoadBalancer` (additionally you may need to edit more values e.g. port number from default `5000`):

```
$ arkade install docker-registry --set service.type=LoadBalancer
```

To change port add `--set service.port=<PORT_NUMBER>` to the above command.

We can check the type of the `docker-registry` `Service`:

```
$ kubectl get svc docker-registry
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
docker-registry   LoadBalancer   10.0.14.107   <PUBLIC_IP>    5000:32665/TCP   29m
```

---

In addition, you may be interested in TLS-enabled Docker registry as described in this [tutorial](https://blog.alexellis.io/get-a-tls-enabled-docker-registry-in-5-minutes/).  I recommend you to use this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I appreciate it! It works like a charm :) Now that I'ver read a little about how helm repos are organized, it's much clearer to me how the magic behind the curtain happens. Your link to the docker-registry values opened my eyes.